# Is there a way to match such pattern with shell or sed?

Tags: shell, sed

I have a file with following output:

```
BP 0 test:
    case    id          Name            
    ======  ========  =================
         0        82  a_case-2-0-0      

BP 1 test:
    case    id          Name            
    ======  ========  =================
         0        86  a_case-2-1-0      

BP 2 test:
    case    id          Name            
    ======  ========  =================


BP 3 test:
    case    id          Name            
    ======  ========  =================
         0        93  a_case-2-3-0
```

so, only "BP 0,1,3" have content, so what I want is, is it possible to dump 'BP 0 test','BP 1 test' and 'BP 3 test' only, just want to ingore the 'BP 2 test' because of no test case.

Thanks for  your help.

Comment: What have you tried?  It's hard to help with your code if you don't include it in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'\n' -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' 'NF>3' input.txt
BP 0 test:
    case    id          Name
    ======  ========  =================
         0        82  a_case-2-0-0

BP 1 test:
    case    id          Name
    ======  ========  =================
         0        86  a_case-2-1-0

BP 3 test:
    case    id          Name
    ======  ========  =================
         0        93  a_case-2-3-0
```

Comment: I'm loving that `RS=''` idiom with awk. Another reason to leave the Perl sledgehammer in the basement.

Answer (score 3):

While you could whack something together using smaller shell tools like `[` and `expr`, it'll be way easier to do this using `awk`, which you'll usually find in any operating system that also includes `grep` and `sed`.  :)

Here's a quick-and-dirty:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat doit 
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/^BP/ {
  output=$0;
  getline; output=sprintf("%s\n%s", output, $0);
  getline; output=sprintf("%s\n%s", output, $0);
  getline;
  if (/[0-9]/) {
    output=sprintf("%s\n%s\n", output, $0);
    print output;
  }
}

[ghoti@pc ~]$ ./doit input.txt 
BP 0 test:
    case    id          Name            
    ======  ========  =================
         0        82  a_case-2-0-0      

BP 1 test:
    case    id          Name            
    ======  ========  =================
         0        86  a_case-2-1-0      

BP 3 test:
    case    id          Name            
    ======  ========  =================
         0        93  a_case-2-3-0 

[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Note that this script assumes some things about your input data.  If the conditions in the `if` statement don't work for you, or if there's the possibility of multiple cases after a single test, this script will need to be adjusted.

Comment: kev's answer is way more clever, but this one is easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

If your grep supports -B option then you can do like this

```
grep -B3 "_case-" <ip_file> | grep "BP "
```

The output for the above is

```
BP 0 test:
BP 1 test:
BP 3 test:
```

Here -B3 prints 3 lines above the matching pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 'N;N;N;$!N;/\n\n$/d' file
```